# C# Calling a .ino File

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

I am trying to use both Unity and an Arduino.  For this I need to have my C# script call a .ino file type.  Does anybody know how this is done?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to make Unity communicate with Arduino? Send and Receive commands to and from Arduino?

Comment: Correct. Is there anyway to do it without uniduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. It is called Serial Communication. You don't communicate with the .ino file. You communicate with Arduino using the COM port which sends and receives bytes with Arduino through USB.

On **Unity Editor**, go to **Edit/Project Settings/Player** and change the .Net setting to **.Net 2.0** instead of **.Net 2.0 subset**.

The code below will make Arduino to be sending "Hello from Arduino" to your Unity console Log.

Unity C# Code("Receives from Arduino"):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

public class ArduinoCOM : MonoBehaviour
{

    SerialPort ardPort;

    void Start ()
    {
        ardPort = new SerialPort ("COM4", 9600);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (byteIsAvailable ()) {
            Debug.Log ("Received " + readFromArduino ());
        }
    }

    void sendToArduino (string messageToSend)
    {
        ardPort.Write (messageToSend + '\n');
    }

    string readFromArduino ()
    {
        string tempReceived = null;

        if (ardPort.BytesToRead > 0) {
            tempReceived = ardPort.ReadLine ();
        }
        return tempReceived;
    }

    bool byteIsAvailable ()
    {
        if (ardPort.BytesToRead > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The Arduino part of the code will be sending "Hello From Arduino" to your Unity Console.(Sends to Unity Console)

```
String receivedMessage = "";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sendToUnity("Hello From Arduino");
}

void sendToUnity(String messageToSend) {
  for (int i = 0; i < messageToSend.length(); i++) {
    Serial.write(messageToSend[i]);
  }
  Serial.write('\n');
}

String readFromUnity() {
  char tempChar;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    tempChar = Serial.read();
    receivedMessage.concat(tempChar);
  }
  return receivedMessage;
}

bool byteIsAvailable () {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I wrote an easy read, write and check for a new byte function for you. You can also send message to your Arduino with the sendToArduino function I put there. You need to google C# SerialPort and learn more about it.